# SetVolumeLabel function getting failed due to access denied error on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uac, windows-7-x64, msdn

`SetVolumeLabel` function getting failed due to access denied error on Windows 7.

Same function works fine on Windows XP.

Any idea why this problem is coming on Windows 7 and not on XP.

Any help would be appreciated and very helpful to us.

Comment: Most likely you need to run your code using elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista and Windows 7 have a [User Account Control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731416%28WS.10%29.aspx), or UAC.  This means that users do not have administrator privileges unless requested for a specific operation or application.  Under Windows XP if a user is an administrator, all programs run with administrator privileges.

The error you are getting indicates that `SetVolumeLabel` requires elevated privileges.  You can use "runas" to run the application as an administrator or you can change you program to [request elevation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation).